# User validation in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

We have BES set up in the server. And we don't have any web service for user validation.

With these in mind, what all are the different types of authentication that can be performed from Blackberry application like certificate authentication  or pass key authentication ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some research on this item and finally decided to go with LDAP based authentication. This has been implemented using the LDAP class provided in blackberry.

Other possible options are certificate based authentication, pass key based authentication etc..